# Past tense of "make up for" ambiguity

Tags: idioms, ambiguity, past-tense, expression-choice

I am in a literary conundrum, I need to use the "make up for" idiom in past tense, however "make" translates to "made", which forms the "made up" idiom, which is fundamentally different from the "make up for".

Is "made up for" ambiguous? Should I leave it as it is or go for "compensated for"?

The actual sentence is "Stuff that cannot be made up for".

Comment: I am a bit surprised that you are afraid of such an ambiguity in the past tense, since the exact same ambiguity exists in the present tense, with the added bonus of _make-up_ being what people paint their faces with.

Comment: Yes it does technically, but at least in my mind it is "make up for" vs "made up + for" like someone made it up for a specific purpose.

Comment: You can reduce the ambiguity by clarifying "stuff".  *'Shortcomings that cannot be made up for,'* or *'Mistakes that cannot be made up for,'* would be more easily understood.

Comment: @Oldbag the context is about irrational craving of respect, due to fundamental lack of self-respect and that external validation cannot really compensate for internal deficiencies.

Comment: I do not think that the sentence provided is the original one

Comment: As @oerkelens says, ["the exact same ambiguity exists in the present tense"](https://www.signals.com/VP0961.html).

Comment: @oerkelens Surprising indeed. You couldn't make it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can either make up to someone or make up for sth, but in both cases you would want to use "made".

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the past tense but rather the passive voice.

It would be completely normal to say something like "He made up for taking a long lunch break yesterday by working through lunch today."

I posit that the second contributor to why your example sounds odd is because it has not just one but two trailing prepositions (and it would seem even worse when phrased as a question or a relative clause).

Activities (or inactivity) are normally the object of "make up for", and in that position "stuff" is too vague as it typically includes collections of concrete objects and other kinds of abstractions. The combination of floating prepositions and the word "stuff" means that when you go from

- I make up for stuff;
- I make up stuff; or
- I make stuff up.

to

- Stuff that's made up; or
- Stuff that's made up for.

then the floating "for" on the end doesn't tie as firmly to "stuff" as in the first phase.

I also note that it's much less problematic if you choose a different word rather than "stuff":

- Wrongdoing that's made up for.